# Move JToolBar between JPanels

Tags: java, jtoolbar

I have a program with the main JFrame and a JDialog.
Is there any way to make possible move JToolBar between different jPanels,JFrame,JDialor or any other container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

After digging around the `BasicToolBarUI` source, when the toolbar is "floated" from it's original window, a reference to the original parent is maintained (`dockingSource`).  When the toolbar is "dropped" into a frame, this is compared and only an instance of `dockingSource` is accepted as a valid drop target

The only solution that might work in this case would be to create your own UI delegate and override the functionality of the floating process.  This is a lot of work, as you would need to, conceivably, provide a delegate for each possible platform...

The only other choice would be to physically remove and add the toolbar manually

Comment: all my toolbars are setted floatable, i can take it from the jdialog but i can't place it on the jframe ( what have  borderlayout)

Comment: Then you needs to provide a simple runnable example which demonstrates your problem...

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dqegpn03x6prl5v/Ganalyzer.jar   just go "Finestre" -> "Konsole"  , there you will find a toolbar foatable, i can't place it on the main jframe